# Sum(bytes)/1024/1024/1024 shows in hexadecimal in aix

Tags: oracle, aix

When I query the dba datafiles for size of db the value is returned in hexadecimal. Is there a db level parameter to be reset or anything else to get the value in number?
It is an Aix box

```
 select sum(bytes)/1024/1024/1024 "gb" from dba_data_files;
         gb
 ----------
 97A1451111
```

Comment: What's the column data type of `bytes`?

Comment: the datatype is number

Comment: Which client are you running the query in?

Comment: using 11gR2 database

Comment: we actually have 2 machines, both aix, in both we have same setup, but this problem is observerd in only one machine